# Adding Key and value to JSON using Powershell and Excel

Tags: excel, azure, powershell

I have an excel file which I'm reading from to populate a Parameter ARM JSON file.

The code I use is

```
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$data = Get-Content -Path "$path\$jsonfile" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$Row = 2
$col = 2  
$data.parameters.client.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Value()
$data.parameters.user.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(1, 0).Value()
$data.parameters.business.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(2, 0).Value()
$data.parameters.dev.value = $ws.Cells.Item($Row, $col).Offset(3, 0).Value()

$data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 | % {
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)
} | Set-Content -Path "$newpath\$JSONFile"
```

I need the business value to be a "key" : "value"

In my excel I have the fields as below

```
Name           Value    Key
$client        Client1
$user          User1 
$business      Bus-key   bus-value
```

I can't work out how to add the "key" : "value" to the excel and get powershell to read it and populate the parameter sheet.

The Client and user values are strings so work fine.

I was hoping for some direction on where I'm going wrong

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you add an example of your JSON/Excel file and what you expect to see in the JSON/Excel file?

Comment: @DarkLite1 Hi, I've uploaded the image of what I'm trying to achieve and excel here:        https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/LW9RP80s

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your screenshot, I think this might be of help to you:

```
$MyJson = '
{
    "FortinetTags": {
        "value":"6EB3B02F-50E5-4A3E-8CB8-2E129258317D"
    }
}' | ConvertFrom-Json

# We will create a hash table containing the required key/value pair
$MyJson.FortinetTags.value = @{'provider' = $MyJson.FortinetTags.value}

$MyJson | ConvertTo-Json
```

It will update your JSON to this:

```
{    
    "FortinetTags":  {                         
        "value":  {
            "provider":  "6EB3B02F-50E5-4A3E-8CB8-2E129258317D"                
        }                     
    }
}
```